# Sympy fails to integrate the product of a piecewise continuous function and a complex function across the discontinuity

Tags: python, sympy, integral

If I do:

```
from sympy import *
x, L = symbols('x L', real=True)
f = Piecewise((1, x<=0), (-1, x<1), (0, True))
g = exp(-x * 1j)
integrate(f * g, (x, 0, L))
```

I get:

> ```
> Piecewise((1.0*I*exp(-1.0*I*L) - 1.0*I, L <= 0), (-1.0*I*exp(-1.0*I*L) + 1.0*I, L < 1), (-1.0*I*exp(-1.0*I) + 1.0*I, True))
> ```

But if I change the last line to:

```
integrate(f*g, (x, L/2, L))
```

I get:

> ```
> Integral(Piecewise((exp(-1.0*I*x), x <= 0), (-exp(-1.0*I*x), x < 1), (0, True)), (x, L/2, L))
> ```

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's not implemented yet. It probably doesn't know how to deal with the case where both limits are symbolic. You should [report it](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/new).

A workaround is `integrate(f*g, (x, 0, L)) - integrate(f*g, (x, 0, L/2))`.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question.  I will report it.  And yes, this is the workaround I'm using. You're also right that the failure only occurs when I use symbolic limits.