# Python: Piecewise function integration error: "TypeError: cannot determine truth value of ..."

Tags: python, sympy, piecewise, symbolic-integration

This code runs correctly:

```
import sympy as sp

def xon (ton, t):
    return (t-ton)/5

xonInt = sp.integrate (xon(ton, t),t)

print xonInt
```

But when the function becomes piecewise, e.g.:

```
import sympy as sp

def xon (ton, t):
    if ton <= t:
        return (t-ton)/5
    else:
        return 0

xonInt = sp.integrate (xon(ton, t),t)

print xonInt
```

I get the following error:

> File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sympy/core/relational.py", line >  103, in **nonzero**
>       raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of\n%s" % self)
>
> TypeError: cannot determine truth value of
>   ton <= t

As far as I understand, the error is due to the fact that both `ton` and `t` can be positive and negative. Is it correct? If I set positive integration limits for `t` the error doesn't disappear. How can I calculate the integral for the given piecewise function?

**UPDATE:** The updated version o the function, which works:

```
import sympy as sp

t = sp.symbols('t')   
ton = sp.symbols('ton')
xon = sp.Piecewise((((t-ton)/5), t <= ton), (0, True))

xonInt = sp.integrate (xon,t)
print xonInt
```

Comment: What is `ton`, and what is `t`?

Comment: Two symbolic variables. This is a simplified version of my code. In the final code `t` will denote time axis (can take both negative and positive values), and `ton` will denote start time (can also be negative and positive).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sympy fails to integrate the product of a piecewise continuous function and a complex function across the discontinuity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966759/sympy-fails-to-integrate-the-product-of-a-piecewise-continuous-function-and-a-co)

Comment: I get the error even when the integration limits are numerical, therefore, I do not think it is a duplicate.

Comment: Read the post more carefully. `t < ton` is a symbolic comparison, not a boolean one. Try `print(type(t < ton))` and `bool(t < ton)`. The proper way to set up a piecewise function is in that post, which, in your case, should be `xon = sp.Piecewise(((t-ton)/5, t >= ton), (0, True))`.

Comment: Ok, I see. I am trying to use `sp.piecewise` now, following the answer from tmthydvnprt. It gives me another error though: `DomainError: there is no ring associated with RR`.

Comment: I don't get such an error. When I integrate with `sp.integrate(xon, t)`, and `xon` defined as above, I get `Piecewise((t**2/10 - t*ton/5, t >= ton), (0, True))`, which is the correct result. I have no idea how you managed to raise a DomainError, but it looks like that would be an issue for another question.

Comment: Reti43, thank you for your comments. I am sorry for causing misunderstanding, but for this function in my post I also do not get an error. I have a multiplication of two piecewise functions, which I didn't post here, as it would have been a very long post. You are right - I will post this as another question. Now I am trying to figure out what exactly causes the DomainError in order to create a minimal working example code. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Piecewise Class

You need to use the sympy [Piecewise class](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#piecewise).

As suggested in the comments:

```
Piecewise(((t - ton)/5, ton <= t), (0, True))
```

Comment: @Tanja for posterity, you might post your updated function.  I'm glad it worked!

Comment: Specifically, `Piecewise(((t - ton)/5, ton <= t), (0, True))`.